# Using XPath to get text of the immediate children

Tags: php, xpath, domcrawler

I have this portion of HTML that I need to parse:

```html
<p>
    names: <strong><i>John</i>, <i>Mark</i></strong>
    <br>
    occupation: <strong>actor</strong>
    <br>
</p>
```

I'm using Symfony Dom Crawler to parse several pages. I need the text contents of the immediate children of `<p>`. Using my example, the result I'd like to get is:

```php
[
    'names:',
    'John, Mark',
    'occupation:',
    'actor',
]
```

I have no idea what XPath to use. I don't think I can use the CSS selector, as it ignores the text nodes entirely. Here's what I tried:

```php
$items = $crawler
    ->filter('p')
    ->filterXPath('//text()')
    ->extract(['_text']);
```

It's obviously wrong, because it takes all text nodes, no matter where they are. The result I'm getting is:

```php
[
    'names:',
    'John',
    ',',
    'Mark',
    '',
    'occupation:',
    'actor',
    '',
    '',
]
```

How can I get text contents of the immediate children?

## EDIT

I managed to get what I need through the `//p/text()|//p/*` selector, but I'm still looking for an optimized version, where:

1. A parent selector `p` is not used explicitly, as in my real example the parent is more complex. I don't understand why `/text()|/*` doesn't work.
2. If possible, it would be nice to skip the `<br>` from the selector. I'm currently just filtering out the empty text contents after extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that library and haven't PHP or that library to test but reading through https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#expression-evaluation to me it sounds as if you want e.g.

```
$crawler
->filter('p')
->filterXPath('p/node()')
->evaluate('normalize-space()')
```

that should select the `p` element, then any child node of the `p` element and then return the normalized string value of any of those child nodes.

Depending on how whitespace is treated, using `->filterXPath('p/node()')` might be needed to avoid empty strings between the other text strings returned.

Comment: It produces one long string for some reason.

Comment: @RoboRobok, that API seems to have a strange way to deal with a relative XPath expression, see whether `->filterXPath('p/node()')`, as edited above, does what you want.

Comment: It doesn't. What works though, is `//p/node()`. Not sure how relatively select the child nodes with this.